# shuffling the first ith column in a theano matrix

Tags: theano

I need to shuffle the first i column of each row for a theano tensor matrix.

The only method I find is raw_random.shuffle_row_elements, but it shuffles every entire row (all columns).

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Does this definitely need to be done in Theano and not in numpy before passing the matrix to a Theano function?

Comment: yes, it's better to be done in Theano. If I need to shuffle the data five or more times and i do it in a preprocessing step, then it needs a significant amount of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

`theano.tensor.basic.swapaxes(y, axis1, axis2)`

This is defined as:

```
def swapaxes(y, axis1, axis2):
    "swap axes of inputted tensor"
    y = as_tensor_variable(y)
    ndim = y.ndim
    li = range(0, ndim)
    li[axis1], li[axis2] = li[axis2], li[axis1]
    return y.dimshuffle(li)
```